# What permissions are required for a User Managed Identity to run a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I am using an Event Grid connection along with a Logic App that triggers a runbook when certain conditions are met.

As a System Assigned Managed Identity everything worked well. I moved to a User Managed Identity and that is successful. However, it's only successful if I add the User Managed Identity as a Contributor in the Resource Group where the Logic App is created.

I have a need to crop the permissions down to what is actually required rather than have this managed identity with the 11k permissions that the Contributor role comes with.

How can I figure out what permissions I need to enable for this role to get the Logic app to trigger successfully?

Can I make use of the tracking ID to get further information as to what actually failed for the trigger? The `Failed` message under the `Trigger History` tab doesn't give a lot to go on.

[image: Azure Failed message is of no help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with no information in the Activity Log as recommended by @jul_DW it was a bit of a hard slog to find out the permissions required to get this logic app to work.

As this is a logic app fired by a user managed identity and tied to an event grid subscription I happened to start looking into those permissions, starting with the [`EventGrid Subscription Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#eventgrid-eventsubscription-contributor) Role.

But boiled it down to a single missing permission in the end: `Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write`.

Plus, of course the `Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers/run/action` permission is also required for the user managed identity.

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably looking for is the full list of the [Azure Resource Operation Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations).

From there you can look for the [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftlogic) and see what operations are available. So most probably here you want `Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers/run/action` and a couple of others.

From there, you can either try to map it with existing [Azure built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) (maybe [Logic App Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#logic-app-operator) ?) or you can even create your own [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) to ensure about a perfect least-privilege principle.

**EDIT :** If you went for a single-tenant Logic App (standard SKU), it is important to remember that [the architecture is running onto Functions runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/single-tenant-overview-compare#logic-app-standard-resource), so it might also shares some operation providers with that one, like `Microsoft.Web/sites/hostruntime/host/action`. In that case, [Website Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#website-contributor) should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned in the question how much I've looked around. I have given the whole of Microsoft.Logic permissions set, but no joy. Still just "Forbidden" as the code. I cannot figure out where to go next in order to provide the necessary permissions. But, thanks for the reply. Going round and round in circles here!

Comment: One more thing - I have a custom role which is working for everything else but for some reason I just cannot get the logic app trigger to be successful without a sledgehammer.

Comment: If you look into the Activity Logs of your Logic App, you should see the run command that failed. Click on that one and browse for the JSON details. You should have an ```action``` field which is stating what action was initiated and got denied. This is one of those you need in your permissions. :)

Comment: Hi @Jul_DW - thanks again for the edit and comment. Unfortunately there is no failure in the Activity Log for the Logic App. Everything there looks good, although I can't actually see any real activity in there, really the only activity I see is me looking at stuff in the Portal. :-/ Thanks again for the input. +1 for a well thought out answer with pointers and clues...